# libreoffice doesn't support copy from calc and paste in writer

Tags: libreoffice

When i try to copy fields from calc to writer in libre the office application is getting terminated. need help on resolving this issue.

i am currently on 14.04LTS.

Comment: You should probably report is as a bug at http://libreoffice.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of LibreOffice are you using? This works fine for me (although under a different derivative).

In Writer, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for "Paste special", and use one of the options that dialog gives you.

Comment: i am using libreoffice 4.2 and the application was working fine when running with ubuntu13.10

Comment: That helps to know; did using "Paste Special" make any difference?

Comment: YES, THANKS. WHEN USED PASTING IN PASTE SPL AND SELECTING HTML FORMAT THAT SOLVED THE ISSUE.